# Google Chrome shows text of a web too big

Tags: windows, touch, windows-10, font-size, tablet

I'm facing some little problems with Google Chrome, there are some webs that the text is too big, as if the browser "thinks" that I'm surfing in a tablet or the window is too little. This is what I've found:

For example, when I enter into www.comunio.es, and I do right-click on the text -> Inspect Element, the text has this class:

```
body.touch {
  font-size: .94em;
}
```

And right above this property:

```
Inherited from: body.notOnly468.touch
```

If I click on this, Chrome remarks the body tag:

```
<body class="notOnly468  touch">
```

If a remove the class of the body, the text is showed normal. I've tested with other browsers, Firefox and Edge, and there is no problem.

The PC is a laptop 2 in 1, so maybe there is some property in Windows that I haven't set properly.

I made another question that I think it could be related, this one: https://superuser.com/questions/1179776/system-tray-icons-too-big

Comment: This is probably cause by small viewport dimensions (i am not sure how do they resolve it to be "touch" device). Anyway - i'd check - and this is not CSS matter, but WIN OS - display settings and if it does scale everything up. (Mainly for retina displays)

Comment: Hi @AdamK. , I checked display settings and everything looks fine